# Wordpress почта и mail.ru

Tags: wordpress, mail.ru

Есть сайт на wordpress с обратной формой.
Почта сделана через Contact Form 7
И есть почта организации на stendi@bk.ru
Куда должны идти письма пользователей с обратной формы.
Письма не приходят на stendi@bk.ru. В спаме их тоже нет.
Если меняю в настройках эту почту на любую другую gmail bk - все работает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Письма отправляются по smtp или php mail?

Comment: используется  php mail

Answer (score 0):

В 99% случаев причина в маилру и ненастроенном сервере. У маилу параноидальные правила, они даже легитимную почту бывает отбивают молча.
Но первое что нужно сделать - это настроить записи домена - DKIM, SPF и др.
См [хелпы на маилру](https://help.mail.ru/biz/domain/manage/records)

Второе - на сайт поставить любой понравившийся [плагин логгирования почты](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/mail+log/) чтобы убедится в отсутствии проблем с отправкой или обнаружить таковые если они имеются.